# the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function using vector

Tags: c++, stl

The example generates the error

> the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member
>   function

and I can't figure out why.

A.h

```
class A {
public:
   void f2(XXX* ..) const;
protected:
   const vector<XYZ> f(){return m;}
   vector<XYZ> m;
}
```

A.cpp

```
void A::f2(XXX* ..) const
{
const vector<XYZ>& P= this->f(); // Here I get this error as well
}
```

Can someone explain me what I've done wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call a non-const function from a `const` function. This means that `f` needs to be `const` qualified as well:

```
const std::vector<XYZ> f() const { return m; }
```

otherwise you can't call it from `f2`.